# Where can I find the key.json when running a BigQuery job in the terminal?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following code but I get this error

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mypath/key.json'] }
```

I know it has something to do with no key.json file in the directory I'm running the code from, but where can I find this file?

I've tried searching `find / -name "key.json"` and using some paths there but I still get the same error. Thanks

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: 'XXXXX',
  keyFilename: 'key.json'
});

const query = `SELECT total_amount, pickup_datetime, trip_distance
  FROM \`nyc-tlc.yellow.trips\`
  ORDER BY total_amount DESC
  LIMIT 1;`

bigquery.createQueryJob(query).then((data) => {
  const job = data[0];
  return job.getQueryResults({timeoutMs: 10000});
}).then((data) => {
  const rows = data[0];
  console.log(rows[0]);
}).catch(e=>{
//handle exception
console.log(e)
})
;
```

Comment: Maybe a silly remark: did you write jsonn or json?

Comment: Anyway, the `key.json` file contains the credentials for accessing BigQuery API. You must generate it first and then put it somewhere in your source directory. Everything is explained [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery).

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. Thanks, I'll check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key.json file is the resulting file that you download in order to authenticate against GCP services. There are several methods to authenticate and one of those is using a service account. The key.json is the file that contains the credentials needed.

How you create and use the key.json file is explained here[1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
This is also a good guide for creating the credentials via the Console UI [2](https://support.site24x7.com/portal/kb/articles/how-to-create-a-service-account-in-gcp-console)